# Varnish cache missing in headers - Is it running at all? How to chek?

Tags: cache, varnish, magento2.4.3, apache2, ubuntu

My apologies if that question is already asked - I searched thru all related questions but found a similar not exact match to my problem.

**What is my set:**

1. Magento 2.4.3 running on Ubuntu 22.04 server with Apache 2

- Magento is set to production mode

**What I've done to try enabling Varnish:**

1. I've installed varnish on my Ubuntu server
2. I've enabled the Varnish cache from Magento Admin Panel

- Access list & Backend host is to be equal to my Server's IP

3. VCL file is exported to the varnish directory and replaces the default.vcl file (with the same name)
4. I've restarted both Varnish and Apache services
5. run Magento (compile, upgrade, cache clean, and static content deploy)

I follow that instruction https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/configure-varnish-commerce

**What I get as a result:**

1. Varnish cache is shown as running (after I check with `systemctl status varnish`)
2. Magento store is running fine (both frontend and admin panel are accessible)
3. Headers are not showing X-Varnish or X-Magento-Cache or anything different before the operation was executed

Attached you may find the result I get from curl -I -v --location-trusted mywebsite.com
[image]
I did not change the .vcl file that Magento exports (should I?)

If you need any more information I am glad to provide.
Please excuse my incompetence if there's any (I am an amateur in this whole process)

Comment: Typically you use Varnish behind a TLS terminator (NGINX, Hitch), but it appears you use none

Comment: Isn't NGINX an alternative and vice verse to Apache or i am wrong?

Comment: It is both alternative and can be used *with* Apache. Often times you use NGINX just to do TLS, then it forwards requests to Varnish, which forwards requests to Apache (OR another NGINX instance). The de-facto standard stack for Magento is probably NGINX TLS + Varnish + NGINX with PHP-FPM, but NGINX TLS + Varnish + Apache with mod_php is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Run varnishlog to verify if transactions pass through Varnish

The first step is to run a targeted `varnishlog` command to verify whether traffic is actually going through Vanrish.

I'd recommend not using the homepage, because Varnish's local health checks my use that path.

Pick an existing page on the site, for example `/test` *(replace with an actual  page that exists)* and run the following command on your Varnish server:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/test'"
```

But again: replace `'/test'` and the command with the actual page you're monitoring. Once the command is running and monitoring log transactions, go to the web page in your browser and verify whether `varnishlog` is showing output.

If not, Varnish is not being used.

### 2. Check the varnishd port in systemd

Out of the box, the `varnishd` runtime listens on port `6081` to avoid clashing with other web services.

Verify the port using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl cat varnish
```

This will print the full `varnishd` command with all its parameters. Look out for the `-a` parameter, which sets the listening port.

### 3. Check the listening port using lsof

Alternatively, run the following `lsof` command to figure out what service is running on port 80 *(the conventional HTTP port)*:

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN
```

If the command is not `varnishd`, some other service is using the HTTP port.

### 4. Next steps

If `varnishlog` does display the right information, this means Varnish is correctly processing requests. In that case I suggest you check your VCL file to see if the relevant headers are stripped off in VCL.

If Varnish doesn't run on port 80, you'll have to run `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish` to modify the running port. When you're done run `sudo systemctl restart varnish` to make these changes go live.

The other service running port 80 needs to be reconfigured though, otherwise you'll have port clashes.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply. I followed all the steps and go to even last (my bad luck varnish was not working) - I edited and changed the port from 6081 to 80 - restarted the varnish - and repeated step 1 but still no logs were shown. :(

Comment: @rt89 If you run `sudo ps aux | grep varnish`, do you see Varnish running on port 80 (`-a :80`)? Please check if the right response headers show up or run a more relaxed and general `sudo varnishlog` command without filters to see if anything is coming through.

Comment: It shows a - 80

Comment: 'sudo varnishlog' show me long list of rows - in many of them I found my website to be mentioned, images, URLs and logo and etc. Also show from which browser I loaded it - is that ok - what exactly should I looking for?

Comment: @rt89 the fact that `varnishlog` is showing things, means that Varnish is being used. So I guess you've solved the issue. If you want to learn more about inspecting traffic with `varnishlog`, have a look at the following tutorial I wrote: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnishlog/